# Implication Of limit f(x)=L>0

Tags: calculus

I know that there is a theorem saying that if $lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L>0$ there is $\epsilon$ neighborhood that is $>0$.

Than I came across the following: if $lim_{x\to a}f(x)=L>0$ there is $\delta>0$ so that for all $0<|x-a|<\delta \rightarrow f(x)>\frac{L}{2}$

Does the first lead to the second?

Comment: Actually the second implies straightforwardly the first, and the second is a direct consequence of the definition of limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are both direct interpretations of the definition of a limit.

Comment: Where do $\frac{L}{2}$ comes from?

Comment: In the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ formulation of the limit, you could choose $\epsilon = L/2$ for instance.